# pgfplot makes wrong log scaling

Tags: pgfplots

I am making a simple semi-logarithmic diagram, with axis set as

```
\begin{axis}[
ymin=0.25, ymax=1.1, % y scale
ymode=log,
]
```

Basically, it works, but with that settings produces tick labels like

```
$10^{0}$ (that is OK), and $10^{-0.2}$, $10^{-0.4}$
```

etc., equidistantly. With settings like

```
\begin{axis}[
ymin=0.1, ymax=1.1, % y scale
ymode=log,
]
```

everything works as expected. I guess that the problem is that the range spanned is less than a log(10). Do I wrong something or it is a known bug?

Comment: Why would you make a logarithmic plot over such a small range of values? A linear plot should be perfectly fine here.

Comment: Because I am displaying a kind of saturation curve, where the values approach more and more 1. On a linear scale, most of the points are at the same vertical position. The logarithmic behavior is independent of the range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is expected behavior.

In particular, the scaling is correct: it is a log scale. What is unexpected at first glance is that the exponent is not an integer. That, in turn, is a result of the small axis range. But a small axis range is not "a problem".

If you want a bigger axis range, you an simply enlarge it. If you prefer integer exponents, you can use `ytick distance=1` (or choose a list of tick positions using `ytick={<list>}`).

Comment: Well, I do need the range which is optimal for what I want to present. Enlarging it would waste diagram space and loose information. Anyhow, thanks for your reply. BTW: is the non-integer exponent the by-product of some internal conversion, or you did have some special goal with it? (It is the first time I see a logarithmic graph  I cannot tell directly what is the value displayed, even if it is at a tickmark.)

Comment: One more little problem. It looks like your package takes over local setting for printing numbers. Unfortunately, our local settings use "decimal comma" instead of "decimal point". I.e. I print "0,8" instead of "0.8", even if I am preparing English paper. Is there a setting in your package to change this?

Comment: Regarding non-integer exponents: they are unusual -- except if you have very small ranges. There is little to be done if you want to see any kind of description

Comment: Regarding comma/point: try using `\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/use comma}` in the document's preamble. It should change the global appearance of all number formatting routines of PGF and `pgfplots`. The reference for all kinds of number formatting options is in `pgfplotstable.pdf` or, equivalently, in `pgfmanual.pdf`. A brief summary is in `pgfplots.pdf`.